# Difficulties with google authentication

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to authenticate google with the following code but google sent me back to the **login page** again.

```
//STEP# 1
                string loginURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginBox?service=analytics&nui=1&hl=en-US&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fsettings%2F%3Fet%3Dreset%26hl%3Den%26et%3Dreset%26hl%3Den-US";
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginURL);
                request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
                request.Method = "GET";             
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/2008111217 Fedora/3.0.4-1.fc10 Firefox/3.0.4";


                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


                foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
                {
                      cookieJar.Add(cook);
                }


                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()) )
                {
                    serverResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();                       
                    sr.Close();
                }           

                galx = ExtractValue(serverResponse,"GALX","name=\"GALX\" value=\"");

                Console.WriteLine(galx);


                //Request# 2

                string uriWithData = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginBoxAuth";
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriWithData);
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/2008111217 Fedora/3.0.4-1.fc10 Firefox/3.0.4";
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
                string param = string.Format("Email={0}&Passwd={1}&continue={2}&service=analytics&nui=1&dsh=8209101995200094904&GALX={3}&hl=en-US&PersistentCookie=yes","**my email address**",p,"",galx);
                byte[] postArr = StrToByteArray(param);
                request.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
                request.ContentLength = param.Length;

                Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                reqStream.Write(postArr,0,postArr.Length);
                reqStream.Close();

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


                foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
                {
                      cookieJar.Add(cook);
                }


                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()) )
                {
                    serverResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    Console.WriteLine(serverResponse);
                    // Close and clean up the StreamReader       
                    sr.Close();
                }
```

Comment: What is the error you get ? in witch point is not work ?

Comment: What kind of exception / messages do you get? What is not working?

Comment: @Younes,@Aristos it send me back to login page.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea an I am pretty sure not many people are going to want to sift through that much code.

One thing that I see at a glance that may be causing problems is that you are playing with the cookies too much.

Create one CookieContainer and just pass it in with each request.

No need to 'transfer' or 'recreate' the container.

Comment: i have only one cookiecontainer object and i am sending it with each request

Comment: @Sanders cookieJar object scope is global

Comment: @user283405 - everywhere you see `cookieJar.Add(cook)` is what I am talking about. not only is it unecessary, it could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [google accounts api](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html#Request) and [GBaseService](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/docs/folder35/AllMembers_T_Google_GData_GoogleBase_GBaseService.htm). I believe you will have to set `HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE` in `accountType` as Marty has done [here in this post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-accounts-api/browse_thread/thread/dcf9f80bf595654d).